# JfreeChart scatter plot click to popup information

Tags: jfreechart, scatter-plot

Is it possible to add GUID to each point on scatter plot so when user will click the point I  can handle the GUID and retrieve some information?

Edited: add sample:

```
package demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.XYItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class ScatterMouseClick extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int N = 24;
    private static final Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    private final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Scatter Series");

    public ScatterMouseClick(String s) {
        super(s);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "Scatter Mouse click Demo", "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis(), true);
        adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis(), false);
        xyPlot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getEntity() instanceof XYItemEntity) {
                    XYItemEntity item = (XYItemEntity) e.getEntity();
                    System.out.println("You clicked at point of series:["
                        + item.getSeriesIndex() + "] at location: ["
                        + item.getItem() + "] with UTL Text: "
                        + item.getURLText());
                }
            }

            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        return chartPanel;
    }

    private void adjustAxis(NumberAxis axis, boolean vertical) {
        axis.setRange(-3.0, 3.0);
        axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.5));
        axis.setVerticalTickLabels(vertical);
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            //TODO HOW ADD URL text information here
            series.add(rand.nextGaussian(), rand.nextGaussian());
        }
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScatterMouseClick demo = new ScatterMouseClick("Scatter Mouse click Demo");
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[this is another post on how to display point information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909636/jfreechart-displaying-data-on-a-scatter-plot-on-mouse-click)

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ChartMouseListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513). You can examine the `ChartEntity` as needed. If you enable URL generation in your `ChartFactory`, `getURLText()` may be convenient.

Addendum: The simplest modification to generates URLs with your example is to enable them in  the `ChartFactory` by setting the final parameter, `urls`, to `true`:

```
JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
    "Scatter Mouse click Demo", "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
```

You can see how the factory adds the generator to the renderer [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1484). You can specify alternate [constructor parameters](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/StandardXYURLGenerator.html), or you can override the `generateURL()` method to customize the result.

Console:

```
You clicked at point of series:[0] at location: [0]
    with URL Text: index.html?series=0&item=0
You clicked at point of series:[0] at location: [1]
    with URL Text: index.html?series=0&item=1
You clicked at point of series:[0] at location: [2]
    with URL Text: index.html?series=0&item=2
```

Addendum: Based on a now deleted comment, note that `getURLText()` retrieves only what the generator puts there. Alternatively, note that `XYItemEntity` provides complete access to the parent `XYDataset`, although you may have to cast it to your subclass to retrieve specific data.

Comment: I have code to get the ChartEntity But How do you extract the GUID form it?

Comment: The `ChartEntity` can access the URL text for the entity, where your `XYURLGenerator` left it.

Comment: I see this demo doing something similar     http://ww.nothingbutclouds.com/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=repo&path=/JFreeChartDemo/src/demo/ScatterPlotDemo3.java&peg=211   but i am still unable to figure out how to extract the tool tip or URL text... if you can help with piece of code - that will be great

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your `ChartMouseListener ` & `XYURLGenerator`.

Comment: edited to add sscce, there is a system out to print the URL text,

Comment: I saw your down-vote, but you deleted your comment, so I;m not sure what to suggest. I've elaborated above, in case you change your mind.

Comment: question is very simple, I am still looking for solution and didn't find one.. how do i add hash code or GUID to each scatter point and get the hash or GUID when i click the scatter point,      Sorry for my ignorance but I don't see how to do it using the URL code.

Comment: See how the standard generator returns the series and item numbers? If you add your own, custom generator with a `generateURL()` method that returns something else, the `ChartMouseListener` will then see the new value. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6295405/230513). If you've changed your mind, you can click the orange button to reverse the down-vote.